# Android Localisation not working for edittext

Tags: android, localization, android-edittext

EditText is not inputing the text  when using a keyboard of different language,the cursor does not move a ahead. While localisations has been implemented successfully ,its just the edittext that not excepting the text for language except english. My edittext looks as follows:-

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/edittext_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/edittext_padding"
            android:textSize="@dimen/inputtext_size"

            android:layout_below="@id/b2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"

            android:hint="@string/doc_first_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/doc_first_name"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_edittext_height" />
```

Note:-
After some more testing,I found that the problem is when I choose chinese keyboard , while the it edittext works with hindi keyboard.

Comment: Had you implemented **TextWatcher** on the EditText? If yes, then do post code in the question

Comment: No have not used that , just used getText() to get the text.

Comment: Did you EditText has a white background?? you are using text color as white

Comment: no the background is not white